# Understanding the satisfying formulas of this simple boolean formula.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have propositional variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ and the following Boolean formula:

$$\phi = x_1 \lor x_2 \land (x_3 \land x_4) \land \neg (x_1 \land x_2)$$

Apparently the satisfying assignments are $x_1,x_3,x_4$ and $x_2,x_3,x_4$.

However I am not clear as to why this is not $x_1$ and $x_2,x_3,x_4$.

It seems that there is a convention that we group all expressions with an $\lor$ between them, irrespective of the appearance of parentheses? Because otherwise we could certainly have a lonely $x_1$
?

Comment: Parentheses are needed.

Comment: The [order of precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Order_of_precedence) of connectives is not an universal standard.

Comment: It seems that the author of this "bad written" formula means $(x_1 \lor x_2) \land \ldots$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for this! It is very useful to keep in mind